# cake php 500 internal server error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

this is my view code working on auto complete , but its showing me 500 internal server error

[image: image is in link]

I am not sure what is going wrong if i'm not using the right url or some other problem.

```
public function search(){

$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) 
{

  $name = $this->request->query['term'];

  $resultArr = $this->Invoices

  ->find()

  ->where(
    ['Invoices.name LIKE' => ($name . '%')],
    ['Invoices.name' => 'string']);
    $resultsArr = [];

    foreach ($resultArr as $result) 
    {
         $resultsArr[] = ($result['name']);
    }

    $this->set('resultsArr', $resultsArr);
    // This line is what handles converting your array into json
    // To get this to work you must load the request handler
    $this->set('_serialize', ['resultsArr']);


}
}
```

this is my view code:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', ['type' => 'text']); ?>
    $.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    url:        "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Clinics','action' => 'search')); ?>",
    success:    function(response) {
        $("#name").autocomplete({ source: response });
    }
     });
```

Comment: What do your error logs tell you?

Comment: what is the dataType in your ajax call?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja 48 Error: [Error] Call to undefined method ClinicsController::loadComponent()
Request URL: /mydentisttree/Clinics/search
Stack Trace:
#0 [internal function]: ClinicsController->search()
#1 /var/www/html/mydentisttree/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(491): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(ClinicsController), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/mydentisttree/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(193): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#3 /var/www/html/mydentisttree/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(167): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(ClinicsController), Object(CakeRequest))

Comment: there is no error now, there are no errors in error log..still it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message in your comments, the loadComponent method isn't defined.

I would suggest loading the RequestHandler component near the top of your controller, for example:

```
class ClinicController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Request');
```

There is also another syntax for loading components on the fly:

```
$this->Request = $this->Components->load('Request');
```

Reference: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: i resolved that error alreay..but the issue is code isnt working..can u please tell me why